# SQL in PHP trying to list quantity column of different rows through php

Tags: php, sql

I have a table of items in my inventory for my game:

Item -- Quantity

1. Air Orb -- 5
2. Fire Orb -- 10

I'm trying to find how to put these values into php variables in one SQL query instead of making a separate sql searches for each item im looking for.

I've already tried UNION for it:

```
$orbs= mysql_query("SELECT itemqty AS airorbqty FROM inventories WHERE username= '$username' AND itemname= 'Air Orb' UNION ALL SELECT itemqty AS fireorbqty FROM inventories WHERE username = '$username' AND itemname='Fire Orb' ");

while($row= mysql_fetch_array($orbs))
{
    $airqty= $row['airorbqty '];
    $fireqty= $row['fireorbqty '];
}

echo "air orbs: ", $airqty, "Fire Orbs: ", $fireqty;
```

but it unfortunately gives me errors.  Im trying to use it later where skills only work depending on these quantities of the specific items it requires.

for example, the fire attack would use 1 air orb and 2 fire orbs  and only be able to be used if those 2 items have quantities equal or higher than the required amount for them.

thanks in advance.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, use SQL IN for many items:

```
$orbs = ['Air Orb'=>0,'Fire Orb'=>0];
$orbs_result = mysql_query("SELECT itemname, itemqty FROM inventories WHERE username = '$username' AND itemname IN('Air Orb', 'Fire Orb')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($orbs_result)) {
  $orbs[$row['itemname']] = $row['itemqty'];
}

if ($orbs['Air Orb'] >= 5 and $orbs['Fire Orb'] >= 2) {
  echo "Fire Attack Ready";
}
```

Comment: hello,  thank you for your help.  how would i put the quantities of each into their own specific variable?

$airqty = *whatever air orb qty is"

$fireqty = *whatever fireorb qty is"

Comment: U get rows of items and just u can iterate it in a loop to show like this: echo $row['itemname'].': '.$row['itemqty'];

Comment: Okay i have it this way

$orbs= mysql_query("SELECT itemname, itemqty FROM inventories WHERE username= '$username' AND itemname IN('Air Orb', 'Fire Orb')");

while($row2= mysql_fetch_array($orbs))
{
 $airqty= $row2['Air'];
 $fireqty= $row2['Fire'];
}

i need the specific items quantity for the IF statment later

air orb qty is say 10  $airorb would be equal to 10
afire orb qty is say 15 $fireorb would be equal to 15

if($airorb >= 5 and $fireorb >= 2){ Echo "Fire Attack Ready";)

Sorry i know its confusing the way im explaining it,  thank you, for helping me with this

Comment: @Achilles100, ok, i'm edit answer as u wish.

Comment: @Achilles100 ok, but who downvote my answer?

Comment: Thank you for your help!  i adjusted it a bit and so far seems to be working!

Comment: Hey i get errors of undefined index when i dont have those items in my inventory  is there  way to make them default 0?  ive tried to put default variables above but it seems to make no difference,  also tried the isset() around each of them. but again didnt work

Comment: Answer edited, added default values for orbs

Comment: hopefully theres a unique index in username, itemname or else the last record of the same item will set the amount